# Inner-dict post data with rauth

Tags: python, rauth

I'm using `rauth` to communicate with the Bricklink API. The basic API implementation can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/robbietjuh/a20b174486f758375224) and the documentation provided by Bricklink can be found [here](http://apidev.bricklink.com/redmine/projects/bricklink-api/wiki/API_References). Method classes are being built upon the API class to communicate with Bricklink.

When posting data to Bricklink, you have to send this data along as the request body. With simple requests, that's fine. For example, this'll work just fine (mind `data`):

```
client = ApiClient(...)
data = {'foo': 'bar', 'stack': 'overflow'}
client.post('inventories', data)
```

However, as documented [here](http://apidev.bricklink.com/redmine/projects/bricklink-api/wiki/UserInventoryResource#Inventory), I need to pass through an inner-dict to Bricklink sometimes (`item` property). Example code:

```
client = ApiClient(...)
data = {'item': {'type': 'MINIFIG', 'no': 'cas358'}, 'quantity': 3}
client.post('inventories', data)
```

Mind the dictionary in `data['item']`. When submitting this request, rauth seems to be unable to calculate a valid OAuth signature. It does not matter which API method is being used - when using a dictionary like this, the request will always fail. Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "bricklink/api.py", line 59, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, params)
  File "bricklink/api.py", line 53, in request
    return self.processResponse(response)
  File "bricklink/api.py", line 36, in processResponse
    elif meta['message'] == 'BAD_OAUTH_REQUEST': raise BricklinkBadOauthRequestException(meta['description'])
bricklink.exceptions.BricklinkBadOauthRequestException: SIGNATURE_INVALID: Invalid Signature
```

Is there a workaround or another method of passing through such a dictionary to `rauth`?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have a similar question